# Tomcat 404 Not Found without Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, localhost

I'm creating a small Servlet project, deployed to Tomcat, without Eclipse (I'm creating files manually and then I put them in the directory architecture of Tomcat).
This is my architecture directory in the folder Tomcat:
...

..webapps

../webapps/apress

../webapps/apress/web.xml

../webapps/apress/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldServlet.class

../webapps/apress/images/logo.jpeg

../webapps/apress/scripts/jps/index.jsp

I want to see: http://localhost:8080/apress/hello.html

And this is the code of my class web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

<display-name>Prova<display-name>
<description>demo</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        HelloWorldServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the code of my class HelloWorldServlet.java (I already compiled it and I put .class in WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldServlet.class):

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hello World</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }

}
```

Index.jsp works and also when I try to watch logo.jpeg (in the folder apress/images)

When when I try to connect to http://localhost:8080/apress/hello.html, I see this message:
Message: /apress/hello.html
Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: because you don't have a file named hello.html

Comment: As @mstfyldz writes, you don't have a `hello.html` file, and the mapping from defined in the `web.xml` file does not apply, because the `web.xml` file is misplaced - it **must** be inside the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Is it necessary to create only a file named hello.html without contents?